# How to get an object inside ListView?

Tags: android

I have tried the code below but its not working.

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, employeeList,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                new String[] { "Address" }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
address = tv.getText().toString();
Log.d("Address: ", address);
```

In my logcat:

```
Address:﹕ John Smith
    Contact Number: 9999999
    Address: 41 Texas 55
    Time Frame: 5:00pm - 6:00pm
    ID: 5787
    Submitted at: 2015-03-15 11:18:23
```

All I want is to get the Address: `41 Texas 55` and store it in a String variable. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: get `String` between `Address:` to `Time Frame:`

Comment: share your adapter class code.

Comment: give more details then only get more (Reliable) suggestions,answers,etc

Comment: Here what is SimpleAdapter it is android predefined adabpter or your custom adapter? Give that details also.If it is your custom adapter means then give the details of the getView() method,etc

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
String str = String.valueOf(tv.getText());  
String address = str.split("Address: ")[1].split("Time Frame: ")[0];
```

**UPDATE**

Explain:

First: I get the string in textView. So str will content:

```
String str = "John Smith
    Contact Number: 9999999
    Address: 41 Texas 55
    Time Frame: 5:00pm - 6:00pm
    ID: 5787
    Submitted at: 2015-03-15 11:18:23";
```

Second, I use split to split str into 2 peaces.

```
str.split("Address: ")
```

So:

```
str.split("Address: ")[0]
```

equal to:

```
"John Smith \n Contact Number: 9999999"
```

and `str.split("Address: ")[1]` will equal to

```
"41 Texas 55
Time Frame: 5:00pm - 6:00pm
ID: 5787
Submitted at: 2015-03-15 11:18:23"
```

Final, I split again `str.split("Address: ")[1].split("Time Frame: ")`

So: `address = str.split("Address: ")[1].split("Time Frame: ")[0]`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.